# Dropdown menu is not showing when I hover over "Planets" menu?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and was trying to make a random website about astronomy. And I can't figure out what my dropdown menu is not working. I googled a lot and saw many youtube videos, but still cannot find a solution. When I change the display in sub-menu in CSS to block, it shows the submenus but in a horizondal line. Should I rewrite the whole code or is it editable? I am new HTML and CSS so excuse my mistakes and lack of knowledge. Thanks.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

header{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../1.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
}

.title h1{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}

.sub-menu{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.rocks:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="rocks"><a href="#">Planets</a></li>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Mercury</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Venus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Earth</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mars</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jupiter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saturn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Uranus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Neptune</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Major Moons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>ASTRONOMY</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have to place your *submenu* inside the parent `<li>`.

Here's a working live [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/gOPGdWB).

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

header{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../1.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
}

.title h1{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}

.sub-menu{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.rocks:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="rocks"><a href="#">Planets</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Mercury</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Venus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Earth</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mars</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jupiter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saturn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Uranus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Neptune</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                <li><a href="#">Major Moons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>ASTRONOMY</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Let me know in the comment if you need a help styling the dropdown menu.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! But I'm still kinda confused. I tried putting it in <li> but it did not work. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong. Can you please show me the right code to do it?

Comment: @AdarshPremraj the right code is right above your comment and in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/gOPGdWB I haven't changed your CSS. Please carefully have a look at the code I wrote

Comment: Thanks so much bro, I realize my mistake now.